# How to hide the info you put in a cookie for retrieval?

Tags: cookies, e-commerce, sessionid

My question is relating to information on the server side that needs to sit on the client side for retrieval, but more specifically, for a shopping cart. I learned to do it in plain text, but I am not sure how to do it to hide what is in my database. I have done some research, and what I found were two options.

1. Hash whatever is in the cookie, and keep a hashed version in the database as well for comparing.
2. Encrypt it, sign it, and if it was tampered with, it will be ignored due to the missing signature. (Not too sure how to make my own encryption)

Are either of these two methods what most Ecommerce sites use and what I should probably use, or is there a more widely used one/ones?

Comment: What information are you trying to put in the cookie?

Comment: What server-side language and database are you using?

Comment: Well, I have definitely learned never to put sensitive data, and so I have decided to take that approach. I would only be putting a users name, and product information that allows me to track what a user would have in his/her shopping cart.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified the specs, PHP, running on a LAMP stack, using MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put anything in the cookie that you don't want to be under the user's control. The cookie is under control of the user. Basically, do not trust the cookie at all. If your design forces you to trust the cookie, change it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an e-commerce site, but here are some useful tips that I follow:

1. Never store anything in a cookie that could be used to danger the integrity / security of your site
2. Only store information that would be completely useless to anyone else, but you.
3. Come up with a method to "disguise" the data in the cookie.

Here's a quick example: Let's say you need to store the user's name in the cookie. First off don't store the name, as that violates the first tip. Instead, create a user-id. Just creating a user-id is not good enough, as that number is still an important piece of information. To make the data completely useless to other people, disguise it. What I mean by that is the following: Let's say your user-id is 1234. Instead of storing 1234, perform some sort of mathematical operation on it and then store it. For simplicity let's say you square the number. Now the user-id is 1522756, which may be more digits than your actual user-id allows, thus the data is completely useless to anyone else but you. To make the data useful again, just simply take the square root of the number. For a real scenario, you may wish to perform a more complex function, just make sure that whatever operation you do can be reversed to give the original number.

Checking to make sure the cookie was not tampered with is also a good idea.

Comment: Good points, but what you are proposing are the two methods I have listed, slightly different of course. I could create my own encryption, but would using an MD5 not be good? Also, I would I check if a cookie was tampered with? Thank you.

Comment: MD5 should be sufficient; however, that depends on the data you are hashing. If someone has access to a hash it could be deciphered, depending on what the original data was. Take a look at rainbow tables if you're interested. Checking for tampering is much more difficult. One easy way to do it would be to make either the first or last character of the data always the same. Then your program could check to see if that flag is there, consider it like a "parity bit". You could combine that with a checker to confirm the number of characters are correct. It's not fool proof, but it should suffice.

Comment: Yea, I was afraid of that. Thank you for your input. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checking for tampering is trivial. Simply append onto the end of the data, the MD5 hash of the data concatenated with a secret that only you know. Then the only tampering possible is re-using an old cookie.

Comment: I think I read somewhere something on on SessionIp. Can this be used to add a little more security, at least from using a cookie on another computer? How can I access the SessionIp in php if you know?

Comment: That's not entirely accurate.. It is also possible for the user to change if some sort of prevention is not taken. This could happen if the user stole someone else's cookie aka session hijacking, but that's getting slightly off topic.. Giving the cookies a short lifetime would help get rid of using old cookies. A good rule of thumb is that no matter how secure something is, it is never actually secure; therefore, trust nothing.

Comment: Sorry about deleting and reposting that comment.. It wouldn't let me edit it for some reason.. I don't know anything about SessionIp, but I would suggest researching website security in general. As long as you follow proper practices you should be fine; such as, making sure to use HTTPS for secure transactions and whatnot.